# Ruby ORM polymorphic relationships, Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, polymorphism, many-to-many

So I am working with the Ruby ORM and trying to understand many-to-many syntax and polymorphism. 
Here are my Active Record relationships so far.

```
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :friends, through: :associations
end
```

I can't seem to get a list of friends per user when those friends are associated with more than one user. In other words some users have friends and these friends may have more than one user association too.

Answer (score 0):

First off, these are not polymorphic associations. One uses polymorphic associations when a model could belong to many models, like a `Comment` model. A user can comment on a post, on a picture, on a project, so the `Comment` model could belong to any of these, so there we use Polymorphic associations. [Read here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to know more about it.

Well, the thing that you are asking is about Inverse Friends, and here is how you can implement it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :friends, through: :associations
  has_many :inverse_associations, class_name: "Association", foreign_key: :friend_id
  has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_associations, source: :user
end

class Assocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belogns_to :friend,    class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :inverse_friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :friend_id
end
```